# Black Dots on Pycharm App Logo

Tags: taskbar

I have recently noticed that in icon of the computer app Pycharm (Python IDE), there have appeared black dots. I see no reason for this. They are not dead pixels. This is only for this app, and only on the taskbar. I tried opening and closing the app and they don't go away. I have nothing more to add other than that I didn't find anything remotely similar online. Thanks.

[image: This is an image. The dots are on the edges of the icon.]

Comment: Could it be a steganographic message, such as on Perseverance? Try International Code, ASCII, wtc.

Answer (score 0):

Try [rebuilding icon cache](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-rebuild-icon-cache-windows-10-a.html). The [option two](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-rebuild-icon-cache-windows-10-a.html#option2) worked for me.

- **Close and save anything that you are working on before proceeding.** The next steps will involve killing explorer and restarting the PC.
- **Open a command prompt.** (press <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `cmd`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- **Clear the icon cache.** Copy and paste each command below one at a time into the command prompt, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each command.

  - `ie4uinit.exe -show`
  - `taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F`
  - `DEL /A /Q "%localappdata%\IconCache.db"`
  - `DEL /A /F /Q "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache*"`
  - `shutdown /r /f /t 00` (**This last command will instantly restart the computer.**)
- **If the icons are still not displaying properly after rebuilding the icon cache**, then download and merge the `.reg` file for the `.ico` (ICO) option [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-restore-default-file-type-associations-windows-10-a.html#option2) to restore the default associations of `.ico` (icon) files in Windows.
- **If still not working, repeat every step, including merging the `.reg` file**

> the ico.reg file.
>
> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> ; Created by: Shawn Brink
> ; http://www.tenforums.com
> ; Tutorial: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-default-file-type-associations-restore-windows-10-a.html
>
>
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ico]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ico]
> @="icofile"
> "Content Type"="image/x-icon"
> "PerceivedType"="image"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ico\OpenWithProgids]
> "AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc"=hex(0):
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ico\PersistentHandler]
> @="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"
>
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IcoFile]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IcoFile]
> @="Icon"
> "EditFlags"=dword:00200000
> "FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
>   00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
>   32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
>   00,2c,00,2d,00,33,00,30,00,36,00,30,00,31,00,00,00
> "ImageOptionFlags"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IcoFile\DefaultIcon]
> @="%1"
> "PictureID"="1"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IcoFile\shell]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IcoFile\shellex\{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
> @="{43372ada-945b-4713-82db-d217b338ae6f}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IcoFile\shellex\{e357fccd-a995-4576-b01f-234630154e96}]
> @="{43372ada-945b-4713-82db-d217b338ae6f}"
>
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ico]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ico]
> "ExtendedTileInfo"="prop:System.ItemType;*System.DateModified;*System.Image.Dimensions"
> "FullDetails"="prop:System.PropGroup.Image;System.Image.Dimensions;System.Image.HorizontalSize;System.Image.VerticalSize;System.Image.BitDepth;System.PropGroup.FileSystem;System.ItemNameDisplay;System.ItemType;System.ItemFolderPathDisplay;System.DateCreated;System.DateModified;System.Size;System.FileAttributes;System.OfflineAvailability;System.OfflineStatus;System.SharedWith;System.FileOwner;System.ComputerName"
> "InfoTip"="prop:System.ItemType;*System.DateModified;*System.Image.Dimensions;*System.Size"
> "PreviewDetails"="prop:*System.DateModified;*System.Image.Dimensions;*System.Size;*System.OfflineAvailability;*System.OfflineStatus;*System.DateCreated;*System.SharedWith"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ico\DefaultIcon]
> @="%1"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ico\OpenWithList\PhotoViewer.dll]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ico\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\ShellImagePreview]
> @="{FFE2A43C-56B9-4bf5-9A79-CC6D4285608A}"
>
> [-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ico]
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ico\OpenWithList]
> "a"="mspaint.exe"
> "MRUList"="a"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ico\OpenWithProgids]
> "icofile"=hex(0):
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ico\UserChoice]
> "Hash"="3v1Pe6oDdBo="
> "ProgId"="AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc"
>
> [-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Roaming\OpenWith\FileExts\.ico]
> ```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers as the linked site might change, rendering your answer useless. Instead please quote the important parts and provide the link for reference only.